# How to count words and group by hour?

Tags: r

I am working with a large Twitter data-set, I am trying to count the word column and group by hour using the Time column, then display it as a histogram so I can see how the words changed over time (distribution of words over time). I was wondering if anybody knows how I can do this with R?

Sample of the data is accessible via this link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JhXEyzkjPs59hVgoS3lW7e0Fcumis62QDUvuMP2q5aQ/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks, 
James

Comment: What have you tried so far and why didn't it work? SO is not an avenue to get other people to do all of your work for you.

Comment: Look into `dplyr` and `lubridate` packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your file into R, (I assumed the variable you set the file data into was x in my code below) then use the following:

```
require(dplyr)
x%>%group_by(Time, Word)%>%
  summarise(count=n())
```

It returns output like this:

```
                  Time      Word count
                <fctr>    <fctr> <int>
1  2015/04/30 21:59:00         a     1
2  2015/04/30 21:59:00 baltimore     1
3  2015/04/30 21:59:00     check     1
4  2015/04/30 21:59:00    common     1
5  2015/04/30 21:59:00   grabbed     1
6  2015/04/30 21:59:00      have     1
7  2015/04/30 21:59:00       her     1
```

Which you can capture in a data table or data frame

Comment: This is not grouping by hour as requested.

Comment: I missed the hour part.

Comment: Use `%>%group_by(format(Time, %H), Word)%>%`.  format(Time, %H) will convert the datatime object into a string of just the hour.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Dave2e

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help, much appreciated. I will give this a go :-)